# migrated WP website – able to login, not able to access dashboard?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-migration

Moved a staging website to a new/final host and updated the database. All of my users are able to login to the new site, but the link that would normally take you to the WP Dashboard doesn't go anywhere...just back to the homepage of the site?

I've tried deleting the .htaccess file, changing permissions for users, adding a new admin user via the database.